# Excel's "filter by cell value" filters OUT. I want to filter IN.

Tags: microsoft-excel

Filter by Cell Value is smart enough to identify and delete all rows containing a match to a list in another column.   BUT I want to capture and keep them!  (instead of deleting).  If excel can identify them and delete them, it should also be able to identify and copy them to a clipboard. How do I make it do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoFilter, just erase all item's check boxes, and check only what you want.

Excel's filter doesn't delete rows - just hide it.

Comment: I'm seeking to match values in column 1 of a multicolumn dataset, with values from a separate list.   If column 1 contains a match, copy that row (or alternatlively show that row and delete all the others).